# Google Geocoder and jQuery Deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, google-geocoder

I was wondering, if there is a way to get jQuery Deferred working with Google Geocoder. I tried something like:

```
// ...

_geocoder: function( address ) {
    if ( !this.props.geocoder ) {
        this.props.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        geocoder;           

    geocoder = this.props.geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function( results, status ) {
        if ( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            deferred.resolve({
                lat: results[ 0 ].geometry.location.k,
                lng: results[ 0 ].geometry.location.A
            });
        } else {
            deferred.reject();
        }

        return deferred.promise();
    });

    $.when( geocoder() ).then(
        function( data ) {
            alert( status );
        },
        function() {
            alert( "Defer rejected" );
        }
    );
},


// ...
```

However `google.maps.Geocoder` doesn't return a jQuery Deferred object, so this code won't work as expected. Is there any other way to do it? 
I'm not sure about `return deferred.promise();` either, because I looked at some code examples, which just used `return deferred;`. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
// ...
_geocoder: function(address) {
    var geocoder = this.props.geocoder;
    if (!geocoder) {
        geocoder = this.props.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                dfrd.resolve(results[0]);
            } else {
                dfrd.reject(new Error(status));
            }
        });
    }).promise();
},
// ...
```

Note: By resolving the Deferred with the entire `results[0]` object, more potentially usable data is made available down the promise chain. See [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)

Test as follows :

```
yourNamespace._geocoder('some address').then(function(result) {
    console.dir(result.geometry.location);
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```